# In r, Is there a way to extract exactly same data frames from a list of data frames without using any packages?

Tags: r

I have a `list` of 3 `data.frame` prepared as below:

```
df1<-read.csv(file="D:/PRADYUMNA MURALIDHAR/DATA SCIENCE/R FUNCTION/specdata/001.csv",sep=",")
df2<-read.csv(file="D:/PRADYUMNA MURALIDHAR/DATA SCIENCE/R FUNCTION/specdata/002.csv",sep=",")
df3<-read.csv(file="D:/PRADYUMNA MURALIDHAR/DATA SCIENCE/R FUNCTION/specdata/003.csv",sep=",")
dfcheck<-c(df1,df2,df3)
```

How do I extract each `data.frame` and merge them all together... considering the column variables are the same?

Comment: Please, provide reproducible `data.frames` so we can help you out.

Comment: You should also format your code so it is readable. Assume no one knows what you are talking about.

Comment: Are you looking for `cbind`?

Comment: https://www.r-bloggers.com/merging-multiple-data-files-into-one-data-frame/

Comment: I'm providing a sample of one of the data frames created by reading one of the csv files:                                                                                                             head(df1)
        Date sulfate nitrate ID
1 2003-01-01      NA      NA  1
2 2003-01-02      NA      NA  1
3 2003-01-03      NA      NA  1
4 2003-01-04      NA      NA  1
5 2003-01-05      NA      NA  1
6 2003-01-06      NA      NA  1
>

Answer (score 1):

As you say the column variables are the same, I suppose you want to append the data.frames to each other rather than merging them.

Further, given the title of your question, I'll point out that `dfcheck <- c(df1, df2, df3)` will not give you a list of data.frames.

My guess is you want to do `do.call("rbind", list(df1, df2, df3))`.

Comment: thanks Roland...I have initialized dfcheck to be a list...the csv files shown here are for illustration, however there are more than 200 such csv's that I intend to use to create one single data frame....the biggest challenge I am facing is to be able to separate the data frames from the list and then getting a single data frame from them....as a list tends to completely dismantle the structure of a data frame....so...I want to store data frames in a list and then extract the ones I need separately to create single data frames

Comment: I am not sure if I understand - but suspect you have a problem with the list in the first place. If you check `class(mtcars)` and `is.list(mtcars)` you will realize that data.frames are lists as well. Now even if you do something like `dfcheck <- list()` followed by `dfcheck <- c(dfcheck, mtcars, mtcars)` that will give you a flat list, which is probably not convenient for you and why I suggest using `list()` instead of `c()`

Comment: got your point! it was actually a flat list...so used list() instead of c()..thanks a lot!